# Lazy Loading API in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, lazy-loading

I have a project that uses Steam Web API to pull player data with the package https://github.com/syntaxerrors/Steam

However, Steam Web API is extremely slow and unreliable. The pages where the API is used can end up taking 30-60 seconds to load and some times even timing out.

There are only a few things I pull, like the players avatar and the url to their profile.

How can I lazy load this data in Laravel, where it only runs the API calls after the page has loaded? I'm planning on replacing the avatar with a "loading steam data" message of some sort until the data is successfully gathered.

Comment: Would it not be easier to add a separate route that you can call dynamically with AJAX that loads the data from the Steam API and passes it back through?

Comment: Ended up being exactly what I did in the end :) I was just wondering if Laravel had some kind of simple way of doing it that I've missed. For example, laravel has a simple and painless paginate built. I was thinking they might have had some lazy loading system built in as well.

Comment: You can *defer* ServiceProviders to load only when required, so you could potentially open an issue on the github project to change `$defer` in `SteamApiServiceProvider` to `true`?